# Why does the word "coffee" have two "e’s"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling

We know what coffee is and where the word comes from. *Coffee* was originally borrowed from:

> The word "coffee" entered English language in 1582 via Dutch
> koffie,[4] borrowed from Turkish kahve, in turn borrowed from Arabic
> qahwa, a truncation of qahhwat al-bun 'wine of the bean'.
>
> *[History of coffee, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_coffee)*

... but why does *coffee* have two *e*'s? Shouldn't it be *Coffie* like its original word?

Having two *e*'s might be not a problem for people who use and speak English but for other languages we can see people usually make mistakes between these words: *coffee* against *coffie* and *coffe*.

Comment: Spellings in English have only really settled down into their more-or-less-standardized forms since approximately the middle of the 18th century. Probably the single most influential event in this regard was the publication of Samuel Johnson's *Dictionary of the English Language* in 1755. Until then, most people who could write had felt fairly free to spell words the way they pleased. English has also had to accommodate a vast number of words taken from other languages with other sound systems; sometimes the spellings of imported words have been adapted to English norms, and sometimes not.

Comment: The upshot is that English spellings are not particularly consistent; it is a mistake to assume that the way words are spelled in English is governed by anything stronger than weak norms and guidelines.

Comment: Because, of all the possible spellings, "coffee" was the only one that hadn't already been tried.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One could equally ask why isn't *coffee* spelled **coffea**, **coffe**, **coffi**, **coffy**, **koffee**, or **kaffe**?

The word "coffee", pronounced  /ˈkɒf.i/, is *said* to be a loan word from the Dutch *koffie*. Which begs the question why the dark red-brown beverage isn't spelled  *koffee* or *koffie* with a “k”.

In Italian it is pronounced /kaf'fɛ/ and spelt *caffè*, and etymologists claim it was derived from the Turkish  pronunciation of  *kahveh*. The letter -*k*, along with *j*, *w*, *x* and *y* do not form part of the Italian alphabet which has 21 letters, consequently the  -k plosive is usually represented by the letter -c. It is, therefore, most likely that the  English spelling for *coffee* was influenced by its Italian counterpart *caffè*.

> > '*Qahwah*’ is the Arabic term for the coffee drink, and while scholars
> >     disagree on the exact link that led to the English word “coffee”,
> >     there is no doubt that it was an Arabic word with some connection to
> >     ‘*Qahwah*’. It is generally agreed that the term coffee found its way
> >     into European languages in about the 1600′s, most probably from the
> >     Italian term “caffe” which was derived from the Turkish pronunciation
> >     “kahveh” of the Arabic word ‘Qahwah’ (قهوة).
>
> <sub>source: [Quora](http://espressocoffee.quora.com/Confusion-over-the-etymology-of-the-word-Coffee)</sub>

Interestingly, in German it is written *kaffee*, which suggests that the Arabic vowel sound ă most resembles the pronunciation of *a* as pronounced in Italian. Sylvestre de Sacy in his *Chrestomathie Arabe* (1806), believes the word *kahwa*, synonymous with *makli* (roasted in a stove), holds the key to the etymology of coffee. Jardin in his *Le Caféier et le Café* (Paris. 1895) is convinced that coffee is derived from an Arabic word, be it *kahua*, *kahoueh*, *kaffa*, or *kahwa*, and different nationalities have adapted the Arabian terms to match most closely their pronunciation.

Here below is a chart listing the different translations for the term *coffee*.
[image: Chart with different language translations of coffee]

An alternative explanation could also lie in the pronunciation of the last two letters in *koffie*, -*ie* is often pronounced the same as *-ee*. In fact the following combination of letters; *ea*, *ee*, *ei*, *ie* often share the same pronunciation, the long e: /i/

In Italian the coffee plant is called *[Coffea arabica](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffea_arabica)*, which is exactly the same term used in English. Note the *-ea* spelling.

> *Coffea arabica* /əˈræbɪkə/ is a species of *Coffea* originally indigenous
>   to the mountains of the southwestern highlands of Ethiopia. It is also
>   known as the "coffee shrub of Arabia", "mountain coffee" or "arabica
>   coffee". [*Coffea arabica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffea_arabica) **is believed to be the first species of coffee
>   to be cultivated, being grown in southwest Ethiopia for well over
>   1,000 years**. It is said to produce better tasting coffee than the
>   other major commercially grown coffee species, *Coffea canephora*
>   (robusta), because robusta cherries contain twice as much caffeine as
>   arabica.

There is some evidence to suggest that the term *coffee* was loaned from the Italian *caffè* and not from its Dutch equivalent *koffie*. The author in *[The Oriental Herald](http://books.google.it/books?id=zJYeAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA379&dq=etymology%20coffee&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tx6AVMeNCOTMyAP4oICoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=venice&f=false)...* (1827) speculates that it was first introduced to Venice by Pietro della Valle, in a letter  written from Constantinople (today, Istanbul) dated 1615. This date is confirmed by Etymology Online's entry for **cafe** derived from the the French term [*café*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cafe&allowed_in_frame=0).

[image: snippet detailing first coffee importation into Europe]

A 1673 education manual for  *Young Gentlemen* uses the term [**coffy-house**](http://books.google.it/books?id=EyUCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA125&dq=coffy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ulGAVMTENqOAywOrhIHACA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=coffy&f=false) and in the following  [excerpt](http://books.google.it/books?id=VsBWAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA117&dq=coffy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ulGAVMTENqOAywOrhIHACA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=coffy&f=false), dated 1710, we see the same spelling repeated.

[image]

However, it was today's spelling convention that was by far the most common,  barring the norm for capitalizing common nouns which ended by the late 18th century, this 1680 link proves that the spelling of [Coffee](http://books.google.it/books?id=TYZNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA182&dq=coffie&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4FaAVL37A4GiyAPsi4DgCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=coffie&f=false) had already been established. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coffy%2Ccoffi%2Ccoffey%2Ccoffe%2Ccaufee%2Ccoffee&year_start=1620&year_end=1750&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoffy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaufee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffee%3B%2Cc0) appears to confirm between 1620 and 1750 *coffee* was the preferred spelling.  Further proof that the  the vowel /i/  represented by double -e had been standardized before the late 17th century is seen in this pamphlet dated 1674, printed only twenty-two years after [the first coffeehouse in England](http://spitalfieldslife.com/2014/01/21/adam-dants-map-of-the-coffee-houses/) had been opened.

[image]

Comment: Well done Abyssinia, for being completely different!

Comment: @PhilMJones  I think *bonn* is derived from the name of the coffee plant. There's always a reason :) **The name qahwah, however, is not used for the berry or plant (the products of the region), which are known in Arabic as bunn and Shoa as būn.** Wikipedia

Comment: It is probably the name of the Ethiopian region of 'Kaffa' rather than the local name 'bonn' of coffee that entered  into other languages: [ "but perhaps rather from Kaffa region of Ethiopia, a home of the plant (coffee in Kaffa is called buno, which was borrowed into Arabic as bunn "raw coffee")].Etymonline.

Comment: Earlier (than the modern *kaffee*) German spellings incude *koffee* and *coffee.* (OED)

Comment: @CarSmack originally *koffee* was spelt with the -o but it was later changed to reflect more faithfully the original  Arabic pronunciation, i.e. they copied the Italian *caffè* :)

Comment: 1620-1750 the different spellings of coffee, which appears to have always been the most popular/common form [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coffy%2Ccoffi%2Ccoffey%2Ccoffe%2Ccaufee%2Ccoffee&year_start=1620&year_end=1750&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoffy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaufee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoffee%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

It appears it is for  reproducing the sound of *[e](https://pronunciationcoach.wordpress.com/category/suffixes/)* that otherwise would be mute:

> - There is only just a handful words that have a single [-e] which is pronounced: psyche / recipe / apostrophe / catastrophe / simile / resume'. And of course, one-syllable words with just one [-e], such as “me”, “he”, “we”, “she” or “be”, can’t have a silent vowel! **Otherwise, there needs to be [-ee] at the end, to make the Long-E sound, as in “coffee” or “employee”.**

Actually, according to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=coffee&searchmode=none) the term comes from the Italian 'caffe' and the Turkish 'kahven'. The long-e sound is  more naturally represented with a double 'e' in English

(from www.pronunciationcoach.wordpress.com)

Comment: So why it couldn't be `Coffie`? is `-ie` short?

Comment: According to Etymonline the term comes from the Italian 'caffe' and the Turkish 'Kahven'. The long sound of *ee* is probably more naturally represented with a double 'e' in English. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=coffee&searchmode=none

Comment: Yes you right, I edited question. and it should be said that we say `kahve` in Iran but most of us get confused about using it's English word for first times. coffee, coffie, coffe? :)

Comment: In German, the spelling is also Kaffee, although a coffee shop is called a Café. Interestingly, the pronunciation of Kaffee varies, and can have either a long or short e at the end.

Comment: the *ee* in *"coffee"* is pronounced differently from the *ee* in *"employee"*. It's slightly shorter in BrEng, I think it's the same in AmEng too.

Comment: @Mari-Lou - wouldn't  employee sound like employ with a shorter 'e' sound?

Comment: I pronounce the *ee* in employee more markedly, /i:/ http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/employee and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/coffee

Comment: I don't know where your quotation is from, but I don't think much of it. Besides the first sentence's hyperbole and syncope [*of*], *none* of the six examples have a long *e*, and non-Americans know very well that *resume*, without an accent, has only two syllables. Trying to find logical rules for English spelling and pronunciation is a fool's errand.

Comment: @TimLymington - the examples are given to show exceptions to the fact that the final 'e' is generally mute. When it is pronounced, whatever the length of the sound, it is written as a double 'ee'. I agree that there are no fixed rules and that pronunciation has no logic, but the suffix 'ee' is always( as far as I know) pronounced.

Comment: @TimLymington where does it say that the first six examples have a long -e? They are the few cases where a word ending with a single-e is not "silent".

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* registers the following spellings, just for English, in chronological order:

> Forms:  α. (15 caoua, chaoua, 16 cahve, coava, coave, cahu, coho, kauhi, kahue, cauwa); β. 16 coffa, caffa, capha; γ. 16 caphe, cauphe, cophie, coffi(e), coffey, coffea, coffy, 16–17 coffe, cophee, caufee, 16– coffee.

So, as you can see, it took a long time for the spelling "coffee" to defeat all its rivals.)