# Why is a coffee bean not called “coffee”?

Tags: terminology, loanwords, food

Why is a coffee bean not called ‘coffee’ when it obviously originated from there, it seems they reversed it to the coffee drink.
Even the [Google search engine](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=coffee&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) refers ‘Coffee’ as a drink and not the coffee bean itself.

Other fruits/vegetables are just called by *[name]*, while their tree is called *[name]* *[tree]*, they call a beverage name by the *[fruit/vegetable name] [type of beverage]*

*(E.g: mango shake, lemon juice,)*

.

But when you heard coffee, it's not the coffee bean itself but the drink. Why is that? What might be the (possible) history behind this?

Comment: [Why does the word “coffee” have two “e’s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211856/)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the word coffee originally referred to the drink, not the beans. It is a loanword that ultimately came from an Arabic word, which referred originally to mulled wine, later coffee.